# problema com acentuação ao importar arquivo texto via php e gravar no mysql

Tags: php

Estou com uma terrível luta para conseguir gravar dados obtidos de um arquivo txt com string com acentuação.

Acontece que todas as palavras com acentuação não são gravadas no na tabela.
Veja abaixo a coluna em branco, onde deveria ter gravado essa informação: 
Aposentadoria compulsória
[image: note a parte em destaque, está vazio.]

A tabela em questão é criada em InnoDB e UTF-8

Quando eu abro o arquivo, ainda utilizo isso: $linhas= utf8_encode($linhas)|

Bom, o que eu percebi:
Se eu abrir o arquivo texto no Notepad++ e conveter ele para utf-8 SEM BOM, bingo, acabaram meus problemas.

Mas não posso pedir sempre para meus clientes abrirem o txt e converterem antes de importar no site... é uma rotina diária e gera certo desconforto tal procedimento.

Eu pensei em tentar abrir o arquivo e converter ele em utf8 sem BOM direto no PHP ou tratar os dados no momento da importação.

Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Eis meu código:

```
        // A abertura do Arquivo
    $arquivo = fopen($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], 'r');
    //echo mb_detect_encoding($arquivo); exit;



        while(!feof($arquivo) ) {

            $linhas = fgets($arquivo);                 

            $linhas= utf8_encode($linhas);
            //echo mb_detect_encoding($linhas); exit;


            $dados = explode(";", $linhas);




            if ($linhas != "\n" && $linhas != ""):


            $conteudo = array();




            $conteudo[] = [
                'funcionario_cargo' => $dados[0],
                'funcionario_matricula' => $dados[1],
                'funcionario_nome' => Check::Name($dados[2]),                               
                'funcionario_title' => $dados[2],            
                'funcionario_cpf' => $dados[3],
                'funcionario_data_nascimento' => $dados[4],
                'funcionario_portaria' => $dados[5],
                'funcionario_data_beneficio' => $dados[6],
                'funcionario_data_beneficio_publicacao' => $dados[7],
                'funcionario_situacao' => $dados[8], 
                'funcionario_regra' => $dados[9],
                'funcionario_regramunicipal' => $dados[10],
                'funcionario_valor' => $dados[11],
                'funcionario_reajuste' => $dados[12],
                'funcionario_processo' => $dados[13],
                'funcionario_data_falecimento' => $dados[14],
                'funcionario_data_termino_pensao' => $dados[15],
                'funcionario_views' => 0,
                'funcionario_status' => 1,
                'funcionario_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'funcionario_author' => 1,
            ];



            $Create->ExeCreateMulti(DB_FUNCIONARIO, $conteudo);
            //var_dump($Create);
            //$jSON['content'] =  "<b>Arquivo Importado com Sucesso!";


            endif;
        }




    fclose($arquivo);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não sei como você esta fazendo o upload desses arquivos .txt mas ja tentou colocar no php o header ?

```
header("Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: eu uso assim:
`<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Eu já tenho uma função para o header:

`if (isset($_SESSION['userLogin']) && isset($_SESSION['userLogin']['user_level']) && $_SESSION['userLogin']['user_level'] >= 6):
    header('Location: dashboard.php?wc=home');
endif;`

Eu posso criar outro header??? OU adaptar no meta???

Comment: Troca esse header de redirecionamento por um script em js ou html e testa com o header que te passei
    
`echo "<script>location.href='dashboard.php?wc=home';</script>";`

Comment: Show @FernandoJunior
Deu certo, alterei o redirecionamento e inclui o header que me passou e deu certo.
Muito obrigado! Depois de 10 dias e muitos fóruns, consegui a solução.

Answer (score 0):

Geralmente eu uso esse script para redirecionar no PHP

```
  /**
  * Função para redirecionar url's
  *
  * @param string $link - Url a ser redirecionada
  *
  */
  static function redireciona($link) {

    if ($link == -1){
      echo " <script>history.go(-1);</script>";
    }else{
      echo " <script>document.location.href='$link'</script>";
    }

  }
```